# I am trying to multiply a select option value with a constant

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna display result by multiplying it with constant in the Id total, where I went wrong?  I am new to scripting

```
 <script>
       function updateOrder() {
       const X = 10;
       var Y = Document.GetElementById("small");
       var value = element.options[Y.selectedIndex].value;
       var Z = value * X;
       document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + Z.toFixed(2)}
       </script>

          <form>
          <select id="small" onchange="updateOrder();">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
           </select>

        <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value=""    readonly="readonly" />
       </form> `
```

Comment: A bit brave using *const* on the web. Do you **really** need it? What is *element*? I think you need `Z = Y.value * X`.

Comment: what is `element` in your code ? and also there is syntax error in get element. it should be `document.getElementById("small")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById` not `Document.GetElementById`  and `Y[Y.selectedIndex].text` :

```html
 <script>
       function updateOrder() {
       const X = 10;
       var Y = document.getElementById("small");
       var value = Y[Y.selectedIndex].text;
       var Z = value * X;
       document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + Z.toFixed(2)}
       </script>

          <form>
          <select id="small" onchange="updateOrder();">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
           </select>

        <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value=""    readonly="readonly" />
       </form> `
```

Comment: Or just `Y.value`, unless really old IE support is required (but better to give options a value attribute).